# Bootstrap 3 column order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a responsive box layout for data presenting and I need to swap some columns from mobile view to normal or vice versa. I've read everything relevant but the push-pull classes seem to just push things around horizontally.
This is how i want it to behave:

Normal view
[image: Normal view]

Mobile view
[image: Mobile view]

This is my code without using the pull and push classes. To avoid confusion the second column has 4 nested columns in it but that shouldn't matter?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
    <div class="tiles m-b-10">
      <div class="tiles-body">
        <div class="tiles-title text-black">OVERALL SUMMARY - ALL SURVEYS COMBINED</div>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width:13%">13%</div>
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:7%">7%</div>
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:80%">80%</div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="my-legend">
          <div class="legend-scale">
            <ul class="legend-labels">
              <li> <span class="color" style="background:#BEBADA;"></span>  <span class="legend">Three</span>  <span class="color" style="background:#FB8072;"></span>  <span class="legend">Four</span>  <span class="color" style="background:#80B1D3;"></span>  <span class="legend">Five</span> 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lalala"></div>
        <hr>
        <div class="widget-stats">
          <div class="wrapper transparent"> <span class="item-title">Rolling NPS</span>  <span class="item-count green-text semi-bold" data-value="15489">60</span> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-stats ">
          <div class="wrapper last"> <span class="item-title">VCA NPS Overall</span>  <span class="item-count green-text semi-bold" data-value="1450">78</span> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="tiles green m-b-10">
        <div class="tiles-body">
          <div class="tiles-title text-black">3 month NPS</div>
          <div class="widget-stats stat-margin"> <span class="item-count semi-bold" data-value="15489">68</span> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="tiles green m-b-10">
        <div class="tiles-body">
          <div class="tiles-title text-black">12 vs. 3 month</div>
          <div class="widget-stats"> <span class="item-count semi-bold" data-value="5695">0</span> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="tiles green m-b-10">
        <div class="tiles-body">
          <div class="tiles-title text-black">3 month avg. score</div>
          <div class="widget-stats"> <span class="item-count semi-bold" data-value="5695">9.14</span> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="tiles green m-b-10">
        <div class="tiles-body">
          <div class="tiles-title text-black">12 vs. 3 month</div>
          <div class="widget-stats"> <span class="item-count semi-bold" data-value="5695">0.11</span> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
    <div class="tiles m-b-10 btm-grey">
      <div class="tiles-body">
        <div class="widget-stats white-txt">Completed</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="tiles m-b-10 btm-grey">
      <div class="tiles-body">
        <div class="widget-stats white-txt
            ">Completed</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the 1st and 3rd one in the same column, and 2 and 4 in the next column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nesting. 1-3-2-4 on mobile, 1-2-3-4 on larger.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">1</div>
      <div class="col-md-12">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">2</div>
      <div class="col-md-12">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/iqGnnjFigW

Make sure you wrap the inner `col-*`s in a `row` tag for proper spacing and alignment.

Comment: Nice one, using the  `col-*-12` nested it is indeed a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Put the 1st and 3rd one in the same column, and 2 and 4 in the next column

```
<div class=" col-md-8">
   block1
   block3
</div>
<div class=" col-md-4">
   block2
   block4
</div>
```

Comment: `col-xs-12 col-md-8` is equivalent to `col-md-8`. And `col-xs-12 col-md-4` is equivalent to `col-md-4`.